# SQL for the web

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

Does anyone have experience with a query language for the web?

I am looking for project, commercial or not, that does a good job at making a webpage queryable and that even follows links on it to aggregate information from a bunch of pages.

I would prefere a sql or linq like syntax. I could of course download a webpage and start doing some XPATH on it but Im looking for a solution that has a nice abstraction.

I found websql

http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~websql/

Which looks good but I'm not into Java

```
SELECT a.label
FROM Anchor a SUCH THAT base = "http://www.SomeDoc.html"
WHERE a.href CONTAINS ".ps.Z";
```

Are there others out there?

Is there a library that can be used in a .NET language?

Answer (score 3):

See [hpricot](http://code.whytheluckystiff.net/hpricot/) (a Ruby library).

```
# load the RedHanded home page
doc = Hpricot(open("http://redhanded.hobix.com/index.html"))
# change the CSS class on links
(doc/"span.entryPermalink").set("class", "newLinks")
# remove the sidebar
(doc/"#sidebar").remove
# print the altered HTML
puts doc
```

It supports querying with CSS or XPath selectors.

Answer (score 2):

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [hpricot](http://code.whytheluckystiff.net/hpricot/) are the canonical versions, for Python and Ruby respectively.

For C#, I have used and appreciated [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).  It does an excellent job of turning messy, invalid HTML in queryable goodness.

There is also [this C# html parser](http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/html_parser.php) which looks good but I've not tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/). It doesn't let you parse pages, but it's designed to solve the same problems (i.e. getting data out of a site -- from the *cloud*). It's a W3C standard, but Microsoft, apparently, does not support it yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is exactly what you're looking for, but [Freebase](http://freebase.com) is an open database of information with a programmatic query interface.